# llegal escape character followed by a space

Tags: java, string, illegal-characters

I'm writing a bit of code to run a shell script using process that loads and runs a file in terminal. The problem I'm having is getting the filename to be recognised by terminal due to the spaces, for example :

```
"$ ./run_file.sh foo bar.ss"
```

should be run in terminal as

```
"$ ./run_file.sh foo\ bar.ss"
```

Heres the code to change it replace it:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Run");
button.setAlignmentX( Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        run();

    }

});
//button.setAlignmentX(0.5);
panel1.add(button);
panel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
panel1.add(button);

menuB = new JMenuBar();

JMenu dropD = new JMenu("File");
menuB.add(dropD);

JMenuItem loadR = new JMenuItem("Load file");
JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
dropD.add(loadR);
dropD.add(quit);
loadR.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();

            int r= fileopen.showDialog(panel, "Load file");

            if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                String string = file.toString();
                string = string.replaceAll(" ", "\ ");
                //String output = aa.replaceAll("/",Character.toString(File.separatorChar));
                System.out.println(string);
                loadFile = file;
        }

       }
  });
```

I have been tried using String.replaceAll but get

```
java:66: illegal escape character
```

i realise that I can use File.separatorChar :

```
string = string.replaceAll(" ", Character.toString(File.separatorChar)+" ");
```

but this doesn't seem to replace anything...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the `\` character (which is the escape character) inside a string, you'll need to escape it:

```
string = string.replaceAll (" ", "\\ ");
```

A single `\` is a escape sequence leading character, such as with `\n` (newline) or `\r` (carriage return). The full list of single-character escapes is:

```
\b    backspace
\t    tab
\n    linefeed (newline)
\f    form feed
\r    carriage return
\"    double quote
\'    single quote
\\    backslash
```

This is in addition to the octal escape sequences s such as `\0`, `\12` or `\377`.

The reason why your `separatorChar` solution won't work is because that gives you the *separator* char (`/` under UNIX and its brethren), not the escape character `\` that you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the string to contain an *actual backslash* you need to escape the backslash. Otherwise javac thinks you're trying to escape space, which doesn't need escaping:

```
string = string.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
```

Using this code, the second argument to the method will be a 2-character string: backslash followed by space. I assume that's what you want.

See [section 3.10.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for more details of character/string literal escape sequences.