# Android: ffmpeg with filenames containing spaces

Tags: java, android, process, ffmpeg, exec

I want to execute ffmpeg from an Android app, very much as described here: [Using FFmpeg with Android-NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605757/using-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk).

Executing the following commands work fine:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 outfile.mp4");
```

or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg", "-i", "infile.mp4", "outfile.mp4");
```

But when the input or output filenames contain spaces ffmpeg fails with a "File not found" error:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg -i \"in space file.mp4\" outfile.mp4"); // fails
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg -i 'in space file.mp4' outfile.mp4"); // fails
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg", "-i", "\"in space file.mp4\"", "outfile.mp4"); //fails
```

FFMPEG also fails for files without spaces but quoted:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg -i \"infile.mp4\" outfile.mp4"); // fails
```

How can I correctly pass a filename containing spaces to the ffmpeg command?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe change the spaces by : %20

Comment: I have extended my question: because ffmpeg also fails if I quote files (even if they do not have spaces) so something seems to go wrong during passing the arguments to ffmpeg from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I forgot one possibility, and exactly this one is working:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/data/data/yourpackagename/ffmpeg", "-i", "in space file.mp4", "outfile.mp4"); //OK
```

Comment: i am trying to convert video ,where user can choose from gallary but m facing issue that uri contain space like "/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20150108-WA0008.mp4" and vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext()); this command not working can you plz help me out whats issue in uri path and how we can fix it.

Comment: Just a guess, but you can try to urlencode the url before passing it.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess , but you may want the java process to pass "\ "    read "backslash space" to the underlying OS when you want ffmpeg to open a file with a name containing a space.

Its not what the java does with the string fileName. Its what the underlying OS and ffmpeg process receives that it will use as 'filename'.  There you want "foo bar.input" to be

"foo\ bar.input"

So, the underlying expression "ffmpeg -i foo\ bar.input"  should work.

you just need to figure out how to construct your java strings so that the process feeds the above expression to the NDK / process layer running the "ffmpeg" command.

[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532596/llegal-escape-character-followed-by-a-space)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already tried this, but when I e.g. pass ``in\ space\ file.mp4`` then ffmpeg complains that it cannot open "in\" (it truncates all after this).

Comment: are you on a rooted phone? if yes then you can get a shell and directly try out all these permutations until you find one that works.  THen, u have to recreate that shell expression in your java/process wrapper...

Comment: Both commands (quoted and backslashed) work fine from the command line.