# Android ffmpeg: Path with spaces

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I have almost the same problem that this question: [Android: ffmpeg with filenames containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697398/android-ffmpeg-with-filenames-containing-spaces)

The problem is I'm using this library: https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java

In the stack overflow question that I've post the only way to achieve is passing the cmd command as String[] (which cannot be done with this library)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Because the video's file path contained a space that was encoded to `%20`, the ffmpeg execution failed. I solved this by replacing `%20` with a white space. And then using the updated Uri string for the ffmpeg execution.

```
String videoUriString = videoUri.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ");
```

where `videoUri` is the Uri for my video file that contained spaces.

I hope this helps.